# url routing in django?

Tags: html, django, routes

I am creating website in django from 2 to 3 pages so the problem is in the html part when linking the pages in html there is two pages now ( index " the main home page for the site - about)
so when I run the server it open the index page and when I click on about link the url will be (www.xxxx.com/about/about) and when I click on the index link the url will be( www.xxxx.com/about) not the index page . so the two link direct me to the about page but with different url

here is the url in the main project :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('pages.urls')),
    path('about/',include('pages.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

and the urls.py in pages app:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index , name='index'),
    path('about/',views.about , name='about'),
]
```

and the views.py in pages app :

```
def index(reqouest):
    return render(reqouest,'pages/index.html')

def about(reqouest):
    return render(reqouest ,'pages/about.html')
```

and the about html page :

```
<section id="bc" class="mt-3">
    <div class="container">
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}">
              <i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active"> About</li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </section>
```

p.s I put the html pages in template/pages folder

Comment: Remove `path('about/',include('pages.urls')),` you shouldn't have 2 url prefixes that include the same urls. Only the last include will be used if you do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `path('about/',include('pages.urls'))` from your main app urls.

You shouldn't have 2 url prefixes that include the same urls. Only the last include will be used when you're reversing urls by name since you're basically defining the same name twice.

When you do `path('about/', include('pages.urls'))`, you're telling django to build all the urls in `pages.urls` prefixed by `about/`, so `/about/` becomes the "index" url pattern and `/about/about/` the "about" url pattern.

The first `include` (`path('', include('pages.urls'))`) means you're creating the urls `/` and `/about/`, which will work, but they won't be named urls anymore since you override the names with your second `include`.

So if you remove your second `include` for pages.urls, you'll get what you want.